# C# winforms login cant connecr to mysql (error 40) /login doesnt work

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Hello i have created simple login form with mysql db from internet example.[internet example](https://parallelcodes.com/c-windows-form-creating-login-form-with-sql-database/) I use xampp for localhost mysql hosting. But every time when i try use login form i get this message. [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFINN.png)
It seems it cant connect to db but i cant find out why.
I think my connection string is fine but run out of ideas and its possible code is just bad.
I tried: using different sql hosting,
         setting permissions in phpmyadmin,
         creating new user for connection to db,
         using different connection string.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String result = "";
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(@"Data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=users;User ID=root;Password=test.test;Integrated Security=True");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblLogininfo where UserId=@uid and Password=@password", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", txtUserId.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text.ToString());
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader["Password"].ToString().Equals(txtPassword.Text.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    UserInfo.empid = reader["EmpId"].ToString();
                    UserInfo.userid = reader["UserId"].ToString();
                    UserInfo.role = reader["UserRole"].ToString();
                    result = "1";
                }
                else
                    result = "Invalid credentials";
            }
            else
                result = "Connection failed";

            reader.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message.ToString();
        }

        if (result == "1")
        {
            Program.openDashboard = true;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
```

Comment: `SqlConnection` is for SQL Server, not MySQL, you're looking for [`MySqlConnection`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection.htm)

Comment: your data base in Mysql and you are using sql API , please download Mysql dll from nuget and use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According with the varius comments, you need to include the reference to MySQL. So right click in "references", in solution explorer tab -> manage NuGet packages -> browse tab -> search for "mysql" -> install MySQL.Data.

After the download, add `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`

At this point substitutes all the occurrences of **SQL . . .** with **MySQL . . .** .